# How do I set different "content" to a group of elements, without repeating the properties I gave to before & after those elements?

Tags: html, css

I added the `content` property to `.tooltip::after` all the elements that have the tooltip class, now I want to assign different values to the `content` property of all the elements that have the tooltip class without repeating the rest of the attributes that I set for the tooltip class

So how do I do this.

```css
.tooltip::after {
  content: "";
  color: #303030;
  width: 140px;
  height: 39px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -46px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 14px 0px #eee;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="list list-one">
  <h2>Demo 1 <span>- Default Dashboard</span></h2>
  <button class="tooltip html">HTML</button>
  <button class="tooltip vuejs">VueJS</button>
  <button class="tooltip react">React</button>
  <button class="tooltip angular">Angular</button>
  <button class="tooltip laravel">Laravel</button>
  <button class="tooltip rtl">RTL</button>
  <img src="images/demo1.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use data attributes and `attr()`.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  color: #303030;
  width: 140px;
  height: 39px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -49px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 14px 0px #eee;
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="list list-one">
  <h2>Demo 1 <span>- Default Dashboard</span></h2>
  <button data-label="HTML" class="tooltip">HTML</button>
  <button data-label="VueJS" class="tooltip">VueJS</button>
  <button data-label="React" class="tooltip">React</button>
  <button data-label="Angular" class="tooltip">Angular</button>
  <button data-label="Laravel" class="tooltip">Laravel</button>
  <button data-label="RTL" class="tooltip">RTL</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this per element:

```
.tooltip.html {
    content: "HTML";
}
```

Do this for every element with it's own class